# Using CONCAT, ROUND, SUM and FORMAT in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following statement in my query:

```
CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(inv1.total),2)) AS invoice_total
```

I also want to add a FORMAT also.

I tried multiple statements like:

```
FORMAT(CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(inv1.total),2))) AS invoice_total
```

Non of these statements worked. Does someone know if this is possible in mysql?

Comment: Please share sample data and output you desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONCAT()` is the last thing you want.  You need to format the number first and then append the currency:

```
CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(SUM(inv1.total), 2)) AS invoice_total
```

I'm not sure the `ROUND()` is needed, but you can put it back if you like.